# Open View in New Window with dynamic filter

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a link/anchor for (Activity Count with status open, due date is Overdue, and the regardingobjectid is equal to the id of current account).
When the user clicks on the link, it should display the view with the following above criteria, 
What I have now is static/default value for filter of regardingobjectid equals to "User1". 
Are there any way to filter the view based on the given parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mentioned code to open view in new window

```js
function openView()
{
 var url = "http://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etn=entity_Name&pagetype=entitylist&viewid={view_Id}&viewtype=1039&navbar=off&cmdbar=false";
 window.open(url);
}
```

For further more details, refer below given link

[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx)

Comment: This won't work. The OP wants to pass a dynamic filter to the view, not just render the view in a new window.